# How to create a data table using an object array in JSF ?? only the last value of the object is getting displayed

Tags: arrays, jsf, jsf-2

View study plan has to display all the subjects students selected

```
 public ViewStudyPlanDTData[] genStudyPlan() {

    wsctype = "CORE";
    courseItems = em.createNamedQuery("Course.findCourses").setParameter("mcode", selectedMcode).setParameter("ctype", wsctype).getResultList();
    int cnt = em.createNamedQuery("Course.findCourses").setParameter("mcode", selectedMcode).setParameter("ctype", wsctype).getResultList().size();
    selectedELC = "71";
    selectedMcode = "MSIS";
    System.out.println("ELC : " + selectedELC);
    output_msg = "ELC : " + selectedELC + "selectedMcode : " + selectedMcode;
    if (selectedELC != "Select") {
        courseItems.addAll(em.createNamedQuery("Course.findByCcode").setParameter("ccode", selectedELC).getResultList());
        output_msg = "ELC : " + selectedELC + "selectedMcode11 : " + selectedMcode;
    }
    output_msg = "Conc check : " + yesNoRadio;
    yesNoRadio = true;
    if (yesNoRadio) {
        courseItems.addAll(em.createNamedQuery("Course.findByMcodeConccode").setParameter("mcode", selectedMcode).setParameter("conccode", selectedConc).getResultList());
    } else {
        courseItems.addAll(em.createNamedQuery("Course.findByMcodeCcode").setParameter("mcode", selectedMcode).setParameter("ccode", Altlists1).getResultList());
    }
    System.out.println("Number of items within list :" + courseItems.size());
    SPYearlists = em.createNamedQuery("Semyear.findAll").getResultList();
    for (Object[] result : SPYearlists) 
    {
        SPYear.put((Integer) result[0], (Integer) result[1]);
    }


    SPTermlists = em.createNamedQuery("Semterm.findAll").getResultList();
    for (Object[] result : SPTermlists) 
    {
        SPTerm.put((String) result[0], (String) result[1]);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<courseItems.size();i++)
    {
    VSPDT = new ViewStudyPlanDTData[] {new ViewStudyPlanDTData(SPYear,SPTerm,courseItems.get(i).getCoursePK().getCcode(),courseItems.get(i).getCdesc(),courseItems.get(i).getCredit())};
    System.out.println("Inside Object Creation" + courseItems.get(i).getCoursePK().getCcode());
    }
    return VSPDT;
}
```

## Data Table

```
                <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="95%" align="center">
                    <tr>
                    <td align="center" >
                        <h:dataTable value="#{studyPlan.VSPDT}" var="item" border="1" 
                                     styleClass="order-table"
                                     headerClass="order-table-header"
                                     rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"> 
                            <h:column>

                                <!-- column header -->
                                <f:facet name="header">Year</f:facet>
                                <!-- row record -->
                                < value="#{studyPlan.VSPDT}" var="item">
                                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{item.selectedSPYear}" >
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Select" itemLabel="Select" />
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{item.DTYear}"  ></f:selectItems> 
                                </h:selectOneMenu>  

                            </h:column>

                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">Term</f:facet>
                                <ui:repeat value="#{studyPlan.VSPDT}" var="item">
                                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{item.selectedSPTerm}" >
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Select" itemLabel="Select" />
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{item.DTTerm}"  ></f:selectItems> 
                                </h:selectOneMenu>   
                                    </ui:repeat>
                            </h:column>

                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">Course Code</f:facet>
                                <value="#{studyPlan.VSPDT}" var="item">
                                    #{item.DTCCode}

                            </h:column>

                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">Course Description                     </f:facet>
                                < value="#{studyPlan.VSPDT}" var="item">
                                    #{item.DTCDesc}

                            </h:column>

                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">Credit</f:facet>
                                 <ui:repeat value="#{studyPlan.VSPDT}" var="item">
                                    #{item.DTCredit}
                                 </ui:repeat>
                            </h:column>

                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">Professor</f:facet>
                                 <ui:repeat value="#{studyPlan.VSPDT}" var="item">
                                <h:selectOneMenu value="Professor" style="width: 150px;" >
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Harris" itemLabel="Haris" />

                                </h:selectOneMenu>  

                            </h:column>

                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">Select</f:facet>
                                 <ui:repeat value="#{studyPlan.VSPDT}" var="item">
                                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox></h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                                 </ui:repeat>
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>                            
                    </td>
                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="center" >
                                <h:commandButton action="#{studyPlan.saveStudyPlan()}" value="Save" /> 
                            </td>
                        </tr> 
                                                <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="left" style="color: red">
                                <h:outputText id="outputmsg" value="#{studyPlan.output_msg}"/> 
                            </td>
                        </tr> 
                </table>
```

---

could anyone help us how to didentsplay all the records for a student??

Answer (score 0):

The UI Repeat tag is used to iterate over a collection of objects exposed to the JSF page as a value-binding EL expression. It is intended as a replacement for the c:forEach tag from the JSTL Core tag library.
Please check these lines from your code:

```
 <h:dataTable value="#{studyPlan.VSPDT}" var="item" border="1"
```

and

```
<ui:repeat value="#{studyPlan.VSPDT}" var="item">
```

h:dataTable and ui:repeat has same value.

Ideally `ui:repeat` should refer to a collection of objects and loop over an array or list. In your case `h:dataTable` is looping over an array VSPDT. So `ui:repeat`should loop to an array under the parent collection of objects.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{item.subItems}" var="subRecords">
```

so as it stands, h:dataTable is iterating over "item", then ui:repeat is iterating another collection
under "item". "subItems; returns a collection.